# How to add my custom scatter to a subplot axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I did a jitter function to make my data become like a Xmas tree, I'm not changing the data on the Y-axis; I'm just adding some randomness in the x-axis that means nothing since the x-axis are independent conditions like Cell1, Cell2.

```
def viol_jitter(data,xpos = 0, width = 0.8 , s=20, c='b', marker='o', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, label=None,  **kwargs  ):
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
import numpy as np
kde = gaussian_kde(data)
density = kde(data)     # estimate the local density at each datapoint

# generate some random jitter between 0 and 1
jitter = np.random.rand(*data.shape) - 0.5 

# scale the jitter by the KDE estimate and add it to the centre x-coordinate
xvals = xpos + (density * jitter * width * 2)

return scatter(xvals, data, s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts, hold=hold,label=label, **kwargs)
```

I also have a histogram like based xmas Tree function

```
def hist_jitter(data, xpos = 0, width = 0.8 , s=20, c='b', marker='o', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, label=None, bins=100, **kwargs  ):
import numpy as np
counts, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=bins)

centres = (edges[:-1] + edges[1:]) / 2.
yvals = centres.repeat(counts)

max_offset = width / counts.max()
offsets = np.hstack((np.arange(cc) - 0.5 * (cc - 1)) for cc in counts)
xvals = xpos + (offsets * max_offset)

return ax.scatter(xvals, yvals, s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths, verts=verts, hold=hold,label=label, **kwargs)e here
```

However I need to break my y-axis [0,90] followed by [120-140]:

```
def break_me():
f, axis = plt.subplots(2,sharex=True,facecolor='w')

for ax in axis:
    ax.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, right=False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

for sp in ['top','right','bottom']:
    axis[0].spines[sp].set_visible(False)
for sp in ['top','right']:
    axis[1].spines[sp].set_visible(False)




return f, axis
```

How can I call the viol_jitter function and decide to plot in axis[0] or axis[0]?

Thanks!
JM

Comment: axis[1].add_collection(hist_jitter(data_list)) ? However it does add the data to one of the axis but then it doesn't on the other one.

Comment: Why should `axis[1].add_collection()` do anything with `axis[0]`? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Oh, when i call scatter it goes somehow to a "default" axis. if i try to plot to the other axis it always plots to the same one. Could it be because of ipython --pylab that plots everything right away? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Why not pass `ax` to `hist_jitter` as well, and directly call `ax.scatter` on that `axes`?

Comment: Okay I got it, I added the axis as an argument to the functions and return ax.scatter(etcetcetc).

Comment: Oh I hadn't seen your answer, that's what I did! Thanks!